# Can someone please explain to me why I get a different output when I run the same command from Java

Tags: java, osx-lion

When I run the command 
"pmset -g batt | egrep '([0-9]+\%).*' -o --colour=auto | cut -f1 -d';' " 
in the OSX terminal, it outputs the battery percentage (Eg. 55%).

But when I run the same command in my Java code, I get 
"Currently drawing from 'Battery Power'"

Here's how it looks in my Java code:

```
String cmd = "pmset -g batt | egrep '([0-9]+\\%).*' -o --colour=auto | cut -f1 -d';'";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
BufferedReader stdOutput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));    
String output = stdOutput.readLine();
System.out.println(output);
```

I thought it had to do with the double backslash I'm using, but I checked and I don't think that's the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered getting more then one line from stdOutput?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read more from your Process, and you **should** use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
for (;;) {
  String output = stdOutput.readLine();
  if (output == null) {
    break;
  }
  System.out.println(output);
}
```